# Открытие и воспроизведение видеофайлов python

Tags: python, видео

Решил написать свой проводник. Уже реализованы открытие изображений и текстовых файлов. Решил сделать открытие видео, но всё пошло не так. Из рабочих способов, которые у меня были, это запуск  помощью OpenCV, но звука не было, и с помощью python-vlc, но проигрыватель не закрывается. В интернете нужного решения не нашёл. Подскажите либо решение одной из двух вышепредставленных, либо новый вариант воспроизведения видео. Заранее спасибо!

```
import time, vlc
def video(source):
   vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
   player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
   media = vlc_instance.media_new(source)
   player.set_media(media)
   player.play()
   time.sleep(0.5)
   duration = player.get_length()
   print("Duration : " + str(duration))
video("videos/example.mkv")
```

Comment: Оригинальный «Проводник» не занимается воспроизведением видео

Comment: Ник Лог вы забыли опубликовать свой пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: andreymal, я хочу сделать запуск видео из проводника, открывая видеофайл в vlc, или другой программе воспроизведения видео. Эту программу можно написать самому, но как?

Comment: Хороший проводник будет не пытаться использовать какой-то конкретный плеер, он прочитает выбранное пользователем приложение по умолчанию из системных настроек и будет использовать его. В питоне для Windows есть специальная функция для этой цели: `os.startfile(source)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597